# Javascript: Add content on button click

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to use javascript to add new content on a button click.

I have got the javascript to work if the button is clicked once but i would like to have it so every time i press the button a new 'hello world' will be created.

```
<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>

 <p><strong>Note:</strong> The addEventListener() method is not 
 supported in     Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

 <p id="demo"></p>

 <script>
 document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
 });
 </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, accidentally clicked it. Thanks for heads up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Hello World";
```

Using `=` will set the content on each click, overwriting what was there before. Using `+=` will concatenate the text to what was there before.

```js
 document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Hello World ";
 });
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The addEventListener() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I want to use a button for the onClick as opposed to using the actual text